# The final word on contiguous iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Following the paradigms of [SCARY iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391705/what-are-scary-iterators), there should only be a single iterator-type for contiguous iterators per value-type.
Here my code for that iterator, working with C++11+:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template<class T, class U>
struct is_more_cv_qualified : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, const volatile U>{}
    || std::is_same<T, const U>{} || std::is_same<T, volatile U>{}>;

struct contiguous_iterator_tag : std::random_access_iterator_tag {};
struct mutable_contiguous_iterator_tag : contiguous_iterator_tag, std::output_iterator_tag {};

template<class T>
struct contiguous_iterator_base {
    constexpr bool operator==(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p == other.p; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p != other.p; }
    constexpr bool operator<(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p < other._p; }
    constexpr bool operator>(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p > other._p; }
    constexpr bool operator<=(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p <= other._p; }
    constexpr bool operator>=(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p >= other._p; }
    constexpr std::ptrdiff_t operator-(contiguous_iterator_base other) const noexcept { return _p - other._p; }
protected:
    constexpr contiguous_iterator_base& operator=(const contiguous_iterator_base&) noexcept = default;
    T* _p = nullptr;
};

template<class T>
struct contiguous_iterator : contiguous_iterator_base<std::remove_cv<T>::type>
, std::iterator<typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>{}, contiguous_iterator_tag, mutable_contiguous_iterator_tag>::type, T> {
    constexpr contiguous_iterator() noexcept = default;
    template<class U, class = std::enable_if<is_more_cv_qualified<T, U>{}>::type>
    constexpr contiguous_iterator(contiguous_iterator<U> other) noexcept : contiguous_iterator_base<std::remove_cv<T>::type>(other) {}
    constexpr explicit contiguous_iterator(contiguous_iterator_base<std::remove_cv<T>::type> other) noexcept : decltype(other)(other) {}
    constexpr explicit contiguous_iterator(T* p) noexcept { _p = const_cast<decltype(_p)>(p); }
    template<class U>
    constexpr contiguous_iterator<U> rebind() const noexcept { return contiguous_iterator<U>(_p); }
    constexpr T* operator->() const noexcept { return  _p; }
    constexpr T& operator* () const noexcept { return *_p; }
    constexpr T& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t d) const noexcept { return _p[d]; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator& operator++() noexcept { ++_p; return *this; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator operator++(int) noexcept { auto r = *this; ++*this; return r; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator& operator--() noexcept { --_p; return *this; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator operator--(int) noexcept { auto r = *this; --*this; return r; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator& operator+=(std::ptrdiff_t d) noexcept { _p += d; return *this; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator& operator-=(std::ptrdiff_t d) noexcept { _p -= d; return *this; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator operator+(std::ptrdiff_t d) const noexcept { return contiguous_iterator(_p) += d; }
    constexpr contiguous_iterator operator-(std::ptrdiff_t d) const noexcept { return contiguous_iterator(_p) -= d; }
protected:
    using contiguous_iterator_base<std::remove_cv<T>::type>::_p;
};

// smoke test

int main() {
    contiguous_iterator_base<int>{};
    contiguous_iterator<int> a;
    contiguous_iterator<const int> b;
    b = a;
    a = b.rebind<int>();
    //a.rebind<char>(); error
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but SCARY has got to be the stupidest acronym ever.

Comment: At the very least, they are in the running...

Comment: This topic is not very new but I just wrote a somewhat identical wrapper but I have `operator->`, `operator*` and `operator[]` marked `const` since I'd find it surprising to not be able to dereference a `const` iterator.

Comment: some random comments in no particular order: 1) There is not much value in deriving from `std::iterator` (besides it is deprecated). 2) would you consider making the contiguous iterator convertible (explicitly or implicitly) to the pointer, or by means of an idiomatic function, such as `.data()/data(It)`, 3) Some of standard iterators are (accidentally?) nullable and the null-state can be checked, your doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't much to say here. This looks really good.

**Typos**

You have a couple typos in your code on your equality operators. You're comparing against `other.p` instead of `other._p`.

**Not restrictive enough**

We have this constructor:

```
constexpr explicit contiguous_iterator(T* p);
```

But that means if we have `contiguous_iterator<Base>`, we can construct it with a `Derived*`. We definitely need to disallow this.

On a similar vein, `rebind<U>` should be restricted to those `U`s which are the same type as `T` and are at least as cv-qualified.

**Add another alias**

Rather than writing this:

```
constexpr explicit contiguous_iterator(contiguous_iterator_base<std::remove_cv_t<T>> other) noexcept : decltype(other)(other) {}
```

If you added a `using base = contiguous_iterator_base<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;`, you could write:

```
constexpr explicit(base other) noexcept : base(other) {}
```

which makes way more sense.

**Missing alias**

You're using the alias templates for the type traits throughout, except you're using `typename std::conditional<X>::type` instead of `std::conditional_t`.

**Line widths**

Some of these lines are really long! Add some line breaks.

**Why?**

I guess lastly... what does `contiguous_iterator<T>` accomplish that simple `T*` doesn't?

Comment: Good ideas, though there was a reason for `rebind`. Adding `force_rebind` to cover the gap left by prudency.... After agonizing over the typedef you propose, I decided to add it as I don't need the name for anything else, like the `base()`-function in `std::move_iterator`. Regarding your why-question: Such iterators have the advantage of not being convertible to pointers, especially to base-subobjects. As it's a contiguous iterator, that's already everything... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701796/for-a-vector-why-prefer-an-iterator-over-a-pointer

Comment: @Deduplicator Having a member like `base()` is good, except that in my opinion 1) it is not base class, 2) base can mean many things. `underlying()` seems to be a better name. In any case, I think contiguous iterators should (also) all have a `data()` function returning the pointer.